# Would a preconnection of DNS, TCP and TLS stay open after being used?

Tags: dns, google-chrome, dns-lookup

Google Developers [says](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/resource-prioritization#preconnect) that Google Chrome closes a preconnection established with HTML code such as `<link rel="preconnect" href="https://example.com">` **if the connection isn’t used within 10 seconds**.

So if the connection is used within 10 seconds, would it stay open even if not being used again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google only specifies what happens when the connection is not used because the HTTP specs already have information how connections should stay open when they are used.

If a connection is used, it is [up to the server to keep the connection open](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19157695/1145388) so that it can be used again.   This is known as "HTTP Keep Alive".

For example my Apache server comes with this default (Ubuntu/Debian) configuration:

```
KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 5
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
```

This allows connections to stay open for 5 seconds after they are used waiting for a new request.   The connection can be used for 100 back to back requests before the server kills the connection.